# TimedOut Exception when register for Black berry Bis push service

Tags: blackberry, java-me

Right now i am working on Blackberry "BIS push service",
when i register with bis from my device it shows timed out exception.Can any one please tell me what is the problem.I am connecting using WIFI

Here i am the url.

```
    REGISTER_URL = BBP_SERVER
+ "/mss/PD_subReg?serviceid=" + APP_ID + "&osversion="
+ getDeviceSoftwareVersion() + "&model="
+ DeviceInfo.getDeviceName()
+ ";ConnectionType=mds-public;deviceside=false;interface=wifi";
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to minimum info provided I can only presume that you made beginner mistake and just did direct http connection without using threads, therefore your http request easily times out. If that is case have look on this entry [Networking, User Experience, and Threads](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/articles/threading/). If you did use threads then you need to post code otherwise it will be impossible to help you with it